SpiDev.xfer() raises Errno 22 Invalid Argument
I'm trying to use Spidev to connect to a peripheral, and I have suddenly started getting the error:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.
I restarted the device and the error went away, but came back after a few more runs of the program. Now, it seems to be here for good (despite restarts). This also occurs with xfer2, write_bytes, and the others
Edit: It's related to the bits_per_word setting. When I set that to a lower value, the problem appears to go away
import spidev
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spi: spidev.SpiDev = spidev.SpiDev()
    spi.close() # My attempt to "clean up" any past runs that could be leaving the device open/reserved/blocked
    spi.open(1, 2)
    spi.max_speed_hz = 500_000_000
    spi.mode = 0b01 # Clock is normally low. Data sampled on falling edge
    spi.bits_per_word = 24
    spi.lsbfirst = False
    print(spi.xfer([38,1]))
    spi.close()
    print("success")

This returns:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file/file.py", line 89, in <module>
    print(spi.xfer([38,1]))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Details:
Raspberry Pi 5, connected to a DACx3202  on SPI1.2. The spi1-3cs overlay is enabled in config.txt and has worked previously.
Python version 3.11.2
Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
I found some old issues from 2015 on this but nothing recently, and I can't explain why the problem disappeared after a restart but came back later.

What does spi: … mean in the code? 500MHz?! It’s not an SPI bus frequency for sure.

spi: spidev.SpiDev = spidev.SpiDev() is initializing a spidev.SpiDev object and type hinting that spi is a spidev.SpiDev object.
the 500MHz is a mistake! It should have been 50MHz per the datasheet. However, that was not the cause of the main issue.

This was the important part:

Edit: It's related to the bits_per_word setting. When I set that to a
lower value, the problem appears to go away

Despite the bits per word being 24 on the datasheet, the RPi does not seem to support such large numbers for that parameter. Once I changed to 8 (and added some logic to send the 3, 8-bit words in order), it worked!
This is what my code ended up as. I made additional changes, but the structure is the same.
    def __init__(self):
        spi: spidev.SpiDev = spidev.SpiDev()
        spi.open(1, 2)
        spi.max_speed_hz = 500_000
        spi.mode = 0b01  # Clock is normally low. Data sampled on falling edge
        spi.bits_per_word = 8
        spi.lsbfirst = False
        self.spi = spi
#<snip>
    def read(self, addr: Union[int | str] = 0):
        addr = self._getaddr(addr)
        msg = [(1 << 7) | addr, 0, 0]
        self.spi.xfer2(msg)
        return self.spi.xfer2([0, 0, 0])

    def write(self, addr: Union[int | str] = 0, data: int = 0):
        addr = self._getaddr(addr)
        msg = [addr, data >> 8, data & 0xFF]
        self.spi.xfer2(msg)
        return


It supports power of 2 (8, 16, 32), 24-bit is not power-of-2 number.
